# php flattening to parent when sub array contains only one element with numeric index

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to move child array data to parent, if it contains only one element and parent array key is numeric. I do not want to flatten it completely. I want to keep structure of the array. None of the child arrays should have numeric keys, except the top one.

My input data:

```
[8] => Array
    (
        [any] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [all] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [f] => test1

                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [any] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [all] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [f] => test2

                                                                            )

                                                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [f] => test3

                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

My Desired output :

```
[8] => Array
                    (
                        [any] => Array
                            (
                                [all] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [f] => test1

                                            )


                                        [any] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [all] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [f] => test2

                                                                    )

                                                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [f] => test3

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )
```

I am trying to work with multidimensional arrays. 
I tried the following function.

```
  public function flattenKeyZero(&$arr)    {

        foreach ($arr as $k => &$v) {

            if (is_array($v)) {

                if ( (count($v) == 1 && is_numeric(key($v)) )    ) { // Check count and key if numeric; Check count and parent array contains only all or any
                    $arr[$k] = reset($v);                      // Return child array by reset
                }else {
                    $this->flattenKeyZero($v);
                }

                }
            }

        }

          do {
            $temp = $arr;
            $this->flattenKeyZero($arr);
        }while ($temp != $arr ) ;
```

I got the following output. Everything looks good except I could not modify it to meet the condition "
None of the child arrays should have numeric keys"

```
  [8] => Array
                    (
                        [any] => Array
                            (
                                [all] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [f] => test

                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [any] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [all] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [f] => test

                                                                    )

                                                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [f] => test

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

I also tried add additional elseif condition,but it doesn't seem to work..

```
   elseif((is_numeric($k) && (key($v) == 'all' || key($v) == 'any') && count($v) == 1 )){                 // if all or any are under numeric index array , remove numeric index array and move a level up
                    $arr[key($v)] = reset($v);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is by using [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) after checking for count and if is_numeric

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (count($value) == 1 && is_numeric(key($value))) { // Check count and key if numeric
        $arr[$key] = reset($value);                      // Return child array by reset
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Erwin, I tried your suggestion, it worked great. I wanted to have child arrays with no numeric keys. I wonder if you have any suggestions? I updated my question with example and code

Comment: It worked. I made the top key to be alphanumeric and added additional elseif condition.   function flattenKeyZero(&$arr)    { foreach ($arr as $k => &$v) { if (is_array($v)) { if ( (count($v) == 1 && is_numeric(key($v)) )    ) { $arr[$k] = reset($v); }elseif((is_numeric($k) &&  count($v) == 1 )){  $arr[key($v)] = reset($v);
                        unset($arr[$k]);
                    }
                    else {
                        $this->flattenKeyZero($v);
                    }
                }
            }
        }